# @PutMapping and @PostMapping annotations on same method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to apply both Put and Post mapping request to a method as show below. It does work for PUT, but not for POST requests. What am I dong wrong?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/PQR")
public class XController {

    @PutMapping("xyz")
    @PostMapping("xyz")
    public MyDomainObject createOrUpdateDAO(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            @RequestBody String body) throws IOException {
        //...
    }
}
```

When I make a POST request, I get a 405 HTTP status code:

> [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound: Request method 'POST' not supported

If I look at [this example](https://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-requestmapping-requestparam-pathvariable-example), same method has same method is mapped for GET and POST requests.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/method3", method = { RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET })
@ResponseBody
public String method3() {
    return "method3";
}
```

Comment: If you already have had `RequestMapping` then `PostMapping` and `PutMapping` wouldn't be neccessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove `@PostMapping` and `@PutMapping` annotations and add `method` to your `@RequestMapping`, i.e:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/PQR", "xyz"},
    method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT})
```